# Is there a hotkey equivalent to exit command?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I have to use `ssh` on regular basis and I would like to exit each terminal before closing the window. This means I have to execute `exit` multiple times. And I was wondering if there is a hotkey for that? I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> closes the terminal but that's not `exit`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. If it was a post I could flag it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> -- End of Transmission.